# Dedekind construction of real numbers, step 3, Walter Rudin Appendix, chap 1

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

In Walter Rudin, PMA, Appendix, chapter 1, I am trying to understand step 3.

Let $A = \{\alpha_1, \alpha_2,..... , \alpha_n\ldots \}$, where the elements of $A$ are cuts, and $A \subset \mathbb{R}$. (Notation: $\subset$ means proper subset. Also, "$\alpha$ is a cut" means that if $s\leq t\in\alpha$, then $s\in\alpha$.)

Let $\gamma = \bigcup \alpha_i$. We need to prove that $\gamma$ is $\sup(A$). To do this, we first showed $\gamma$ is an upperbound of $A$. To show that $\gamma$ is the *least* upperbound, we let $\delta<\gamma$. For cuts, $\delta<\gamma$ by definition means that $\delta\subset\gamma$.
So there is an $s\in \gamma$ such that $s\notin \delta$.  At this point, Rudin concludes that $\delta <\alpha_i$ for some $\alpha_i\in A$, and hence, $\delta$ is not an upper bound of $A$.

So my question is: there is nothing in this proof to indicate that all the elements in $\delta$ belong to any one specific $\alpha_i\in A$. We know only that the elements of $\delta$ all belong to $\bigcup \alpha_i$. How do we complete the proof?

Comment: There is a lot of context lacking here. Or are you assuming that we all have a copy of PMA at hand?

Comment: My original answer was not helpful because I didn’t realize what you were asking. I’ve edited both the question and the answer to clarify things (and hopefully stave off the question being closed).

Answer (score 1):

The hypothesis tells us that $\delta\subset\bigcup\alpha_i$, and we want to show that there is an $\alpha_i$ such that $\delta\subset\alpha_i$. That will imply that if $\delta<\gamma$, then $\delta$ is not an upper bound of $A$.

We know that there is an $s\in\bigcup\alpha_i$ such that $s\not\in\delta$. Since $s\in\bigcup\alpha_i$, we have $s\in\alpha_i$ for some $\alpha_i$. Now we use the fact that $\alpha_i$ and $\delta$ are cuts to show that $\delta\subseteq\alpha_i$. If that were not true, then we would have a $t\in\delta$ with $t\not\in\alpha_i$. Since $s\in\alpha_i$ and $t\not\in\alpha_i$, we cannot have $t\leq s$, since $\alpha_i$ is a cut. So $t>s$. But $t\in\delta$ and $\delta$ is a cut, so we would have $s\in\delta$. Contradiction, so $\delta\subseteq\alpha_i$. Since $s\in\alpha_i$ but $s\not\in\alpha_i$, in fact $\delta\subset\alpha_i$. QED